# Spring Data JPA - multiple OR clauses

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Consider the following:

```
interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {
    List<Ticket> findByOpenDateBetweenOrCloseDateBetweenAndPersonIdAndType(Timestamp start1, Timestamp end1, Timestamp start2, Timestamp end2, Integer personId, TicketType type)
}
```

The following SQL is generated:

```
select
    ticket0_.id as id1_10_,
    ticket0_.close_date as close_da2_10_,
    ticket0_.complaint as complain3_10_,
    ticket0_.connection_id as connecti4_10_,
    ticket0_.district_id as district5_10_,
    ticket0_.open_date as open_dat6_10_,
    ticket0_.person_id as person_i7_10_,
    ticket0_.public_id as public_i8_10_,
    ticket0_.ticket_queues_id as ticket_q9_10_,
    ticket0_.ticket_statuses_id as ticket_10_10_,
    ticket0_.ticket_types_id as ticket_11_10_,
    ticket0_.users_id as users_i12_10_ 
from
    ticket_tickets ticket0_ 
left outer join
    ticket_types tickettype1_ 
        on ticket0_.ticket_types_id=tickettype1_.id 
where
    ticket0_.open_date between ? and ? 
    or (
        ticket0_.close_date between ? and ?
    ) 
    and ticket0_.person_id=? 
    and tickettype1_.id=?
```

What I need is that both BETWEENs are IN the same parenthesis, like this:

```
( ticket0_.open_date between ? and ? OR ticket0_.close_date between ? and ? )
```

Is there a way I can do this just by changing the method name or I'll have to take the custom @Query approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *@Query* approach. It's much simplier. The query builder mechanism should be used to write simple queries. You will also improve your code readability.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it is what I ended up doing... But it still would be interesting to know a way to control the OR clause in our queries... Even a simpler one like "findBy(ThisOrThis)AndThat"

Comment: Thanks! I can tell you i searched a lot before answering and i had a similar problem with one query in which i had to search for 3 optional parameters. I red all the tutorials and the documentations i could find, i even search in books but i never find out how to do this. I think the query builder mechanism was developed to write really simple queries, like the ones you find in the spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html